# Class 'Zend_Form_Subform' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, fatal-error, zend-form-sub-form

What could be the possible reason for getting

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Form_Subform' not found 
in /path/application/forms/formName.php on line 2
```

on a remote server when things are working fine locally. The problem is only with `Zend_Form_Subform` and rest all other forms (without any subform) and views are working fine.

Am i missing something under `application.ini` for subforms?

Comment: the most obvious reasons would be that 1) the file does not exist, 2) the include path is not configured properly 3) the ZF autoloader is not configured correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is most likely a case-ing error. Please update your class name to `Zend_Form_SubForm` (notice the capital F).

It probably works on localhost because you are running Windows (?) which is case-insensitive, but when you deploy, you are probably deploying on UNIX (?) which is case-sensitive.